# Import an excel table in a access file USING OFFICE 2010

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, excel, import

i'm a newbye I have a problem with the vba code to import data from a table in excel file access. Using Office 2010, but the launch of the code gives me an error:
(translate from Italian)
run-time error -2147217865 (80040e37) Microsoft Access Database engine cannot find object 'INCONTRI$A1:I108468.
Make sure the object exists and that its name and the path you typed BE CORRECTED.

HERE IS THE CODE:

VB:

```
Sub EXPORT2ACCESS() 
    Dim ultimariga As Long 
    Dim ultimacolonna As Integer 
    Dim foglio, finesel As String 
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\TOTALBET\TOTALBET_XML_DB.accdb" 
    dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName 
    For i = 1 To 4 
        ultimariga = Sheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
        ultimacolonna = Sheets(i).Cells(1, Sheets(i).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
        finesel = Application.ConvertFormula("R" & ultimariga & "C" & ultimacolonna, xlR1C1, xlA1, toAbsolute:=xlRelative) 
        foglio = Application.Sheets(i).Name 
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
        Dim cmd As ADODB.Command 
        dsh = "[" & Application.Sheets(i).Name & "$A1:" & finesel & "]" 
        cn.Open strCon 
        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command 
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText 
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete * from " & foglio 
        cmd.ActiveConnection = cn.ConnectionString 
        cmd.Execute 
        With Sheets(i) 
            For x = 1 To ultimacolonna 
                campo = "[" & .Cells(1, x).Value & "]" 
                If x = 1 Then 
                    stringa = campo 
                Else 
                    stringa = stringa & ", " & campo 
                End If 
            Next x 
        End With 
         ''Insert into a table called
        strsql = "INSERT INTO " & foglio & "(" & stringa & ") " 
        strsql = strsql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh 
        Debug.Print strsql 
         ''Execute the statement
        cn.Execute strsql 
    Next i 
End Sub
```

the table "incontri" exists in my excel file and contain data. same sub worked for other sheets without problems and insert data in access table.

string that pass to exceute is:

VB:

```
INSERT INTO INCONTRI([Static_ID], [Stage_ID], [Season], [Number], [Data], [Time], [Status], [Venue_ID], [League]) SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test xml.xlsm].[INCONTRI$A1:I108468]
```

Here is files (too big to put in forum, sorry:

Excel file with code and data: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9350024_63096411_117675

Access file: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9350024_63096411_117635

I'm going crazy to understand where the error is please help!
Thanks in advance to all the people who want to help me figure out where I'm wrong.
greetings
Vincent

Comment: Does it really import 108,468 records?!?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find it easier to do this from Access. Access uses VBA like Excel, so you shouldn't have much trouble with it.

In Access, there's a command called **DoCmd.TransferText**. [Click here for the full syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Do a search for more examples. Good luck.